# How can I take a term out of an integration?

Tags: integration

Sorry if the question is not worded correctly, I don't really know how to word it.

What I mean is this...
Assuming, for example, we had and intergration such as:

$$\int x^5 + 6 \, dx \quad= \quad {x^6\over 6} + 6x + C$$

Is it at all possible to move the $6$ that's in the in the intergration, out of the intergration?

I know it seems like a dumb question, but this is really going to help me.

Comment: By move the 6 out, I mean before the intergration takes part.

Comment: Frankly, you're asking the wrong question. Mathematics isn't about knowing when it is possible to **move** something here or there. Rather it is about knowing what each thing means so that you know what expressions are **equal**. So the right question would be "What does integration mean?" which would then tell you what things are equal to the integral you have on the left-hand side.

Comment: @user21820 I know what intergration means. Perhaps I worded it wrong haha. This question is an over-simplifyed version of a more complicated problem I have...I thought if I could answer this, I could find the solution to my problem.

Comment: Yeah but everyone has their own way of understanding things. I would say you can assume that you can take $6$ off from $x^5$ but then you'll have to put it in a separate integral sign ($\int (x^5+6)dx = \int x^5 dx + \int 6 dx$). But it is pretty easy to integrate $6$ so you can write as $\int (x^5+6)dx = \int x^5 dx + 6x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** have
$$\int x^5+6\,dx = \int x^5dx + 6.$$
What you  **can** have is
$$\int x^5+6\,dx = \int x^5\, dx +\int 6\,dx.$$
This is am important property know regarding integrals.

---

Addendum: You can also have
$$\int x^5+6\,dx = 6\int\frac{1}{6}x^5+1\,dx.$$
These a basic properties of integrals. Try reviewing them.
[This link](http://www.math.pitt.edu/~sparling/052/23052/23052notes/23052notestojan14th/node6.html) might be helpful.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! YOU'RE A GENIUS!!!! How did this not pop into my head sooner? Haha. This has helped me more than you can imagine :).

Comment: @MaxEchendu: And that's why I said you probably don't really know integration. Because integration was defined precisely to satisfy this basic property (called additivity).

Comment: My name is also Max. I am sending you my brain powers ~~~~~~~ :D

Comment: @MaxEchendu: And if your teachers didn't tell you the full motivation for integration, then it's not your fault for not knowing this. But you should always be asking for the real motivation behind mathematical constructs rather than just asking how to manipulate them.

Comment: @user21820 Yh I suppose you're right. I'll do more research on intergration :). Thank you :)

Comment: @MaxEchendu: One of the original motivations was to find the area under a curve as defined by better and better approximations by rectangles. This motivation leads to both the desire for additivity (since we want the total area of disjoint pieces is the sum of areas) as well as the definition of the Riemann integral (where the width of rectangles are made sufficiently small for any required precision). You might find http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/AreaProblem.aspx helpful.

Comment: @user21820 So much info haha. I owe you one :D